# Firebase index error, Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution

Tags: firebase, flutter

I got this error.
I searched about this. and it means firebase needs index.

```
E/flutter (10630): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.
E/flutter (10630): #0      MethodChannelQuery.get
```

Below is my code and it uses only 1 parameter(id)
But i heard firebase index is required in case of more than 2 para used to search.
So i don't know what to change...

```
  await commentDocument.set(newComment.toJson());
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> outDatedPosts = await firestore
        .collectionGroup(MAIN_FEED)
        .where('id', isEqualTo: post.id)
        .get();
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Did you find a solution or where the problem is? I am facing the same problem.